# How to update specific element in tkinter window before mainloop

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to update a tkinter label to say some text, then have my computer speak it.

For some reason, no matter where I put the code, the computer speaks the whole thing before it inserts it into the label.

I am making a chatbot - Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import choice
import os

ask = ["hi", "hello"]
hi = ["hi", "hello", "Hello too"]
error = ["sorry, i don't know", "what u said?"]

root = Tk()
user = StringVar()
bot = StringVar()

root.title(" Simple ChatBot ")
Label(root, text=" user : ").pack(side=LEFT)
Entry(root, textvariable=user).pack(side=LEFT)
Label(root, text=" Bot  : ").pack(side=LEFT)
Entry(root, textvariable=bot).pack(side=LEFT)


def main():
    question = user.get()
    if question in ask:
        response = choice(hi)
        bot.set(response)
        os.system("say '" + response + "'")
    else:
        bot.set(choice(error))


Button(root, text="speak", command=main).pack(side=LEFT)

mainloop()
```

> The desired result is the program inserting the response into the label, THEN saying it.

For some reason, it does the opposite.

Comment: `root.update_idletasks()` should give the GUI a chance to update itself after your var change.

Comment: @jasonharper where should I put that?

Comment: @jasonharper The result did not change.

Comment: You should put the line `root.update_idletasks()` before `os.system(...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 Nothing changed...

Comment: Don't know why it does not work in your environment, but it works in mine (both Windows and Linux).  Another suggestion: try changing `os.system(...)` to `root.after(100, os.system, f"say '{response}'")`.

Comment: @acw1668 It worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `os.system(...)` to `root.after(100, os.system, f"say '{response}'")`

> Credit: acw1668